# event.currentTarget contains the event.target? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, events

I know that `target` is the element that triggered the event, the one that the user clicked on, and the `currentTarget` is the element that the event listener is attached to.

I want to validate if the `event.currentTarget` contains the `event.target`. Cause I don't want to emit an event if I lose focus for the components child.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think `event.currentTarget` always contains `event.target`, because the event can only be triggered if you target something within the one that the listener is attached to.

Comment: But if you want to verify, use `if (event.currentTarget.contains(event.target))`

Comment: What does this have to do with losing focus? I think you may be confusing different things.

Comment: some events are only fired on loss of focus, you'll need to provide more context.